# I am not able to get required output out of max_element()

Tags: c++

I am giving input 1 2 3 4 5 to this code snippet and keep getting O as an output. I want 5(the maximum element) as the required output.

```
int main()
{
int inp;
std::vector<int> A;
for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
{
        cin >> inp;
        A.push_back(inp);
}
int i1 = *max_element(A.begin(), A.end());
cout << A[i1];
}
```

Comment: The documentation of the function is really clear: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element try printing i1

Comment: As you're learning `<algorithm>`, consider this for reading in the numbers as well: `std::vector<int> A(5);` and then `std::copy_n(std::istream_iterator<int>(std::cin), A.size(), A.begin());`... isn't C++ nice? :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`*max_element` returns the element, not the index, so it should be:

```
int i1 = *std::max_element(A.begin(), A.end());
std::cout << i1;
```